# CodeIgniter - checking data and receiving 'Trying to get property of non-object'

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im trying to test a pin number in the database compared to one entered by a user, whenever i run it i get a 'Trying to get property on non-object' error ... I cant seem to spot where im going wrong, could someone please help me out ... Its saying the error is on the $thepin = $pins->pin; line

The code i have in my controller is as follows:

```
function check_pin()
{
$pin = md5($this->input->post('oldpin'));
$email = $this->input->post('email');

$existingpin = $this->users->get_pin_by_email($email);
foreach($existingpin as $pins){
    $thepin = $pins->pin;
}

if($pin != $thepin){
    $this->form_validation->set_message('check_pin', 'The Old Pin Number does not match the existing one');
    return FALSE;
} else {
    return TRUE;
}
}
```

and the following is the code in my model

```
function get_pin_by_email($emailaddress)
{
$this->db->where('LOWER(email)=', strtolower($emailaddress));
$query = $this->db->get($this->table_name);
if ($query->num_rows() == 1) return $query->row();
return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Controller code should be:-

```
function check_pin()
{
  $pin = md5($this->input->post('oldpin'));
  $email = $this->input->post('email');

  $existingpin = $this->users->get_pin_by_email($email);
  foreach($existingpin as $pins){
    // Check for the NULL return
    if ($pins != NULL && is_object($pins)) {
      $thepin = $pins->pin;
    }
  }

  if($pin != $thepin){
    $this->form_validation->set_message('check_pin', 'The Old Pin Number does not match the existing one');
    return FALSE;
  } else {
    return TRUE;
  }
}
```

If you look closely in the model code, you will find that you are returning two data types - one is `Object` & another is `NULL`. So in your controller code, you should also check that accordingly.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @BigJobbies - Can you please try my edited answer (with an added comparison)?